# Set checked value to 0 not 1

Tags: php, magento

The functionality as intended is that the user inputs a qty of components which is then added to the cart.

The problem here is that through Magento Bundles a checkbox is required to input multiple selections with different quantities. The below code enables all checkboxes which enables the qty input fields and then hides the checkboxes.

When the checkboxes are enabled the qty input value is defaulting to 1 even though the displayed qty is 0 (generated in the select options for $i=0 operation).

Therefore even if you select 2 of one component, 1 of every other component is added to the cart. Selecting 0 from the input dropdown does not return that value when the form is submitted.

I can't figure out how to set the checked default value to 0 instead of 1. The only other thing I can think of is collecting the current user input however I when I try storing the input as a variable via $_POST[] it returns nothing.

Would anyone have any other ideas or perhaps know how to change the default checked value from 1 to 0?

[Input section. Drop down menu is enabled when checkbox is checked. Checkbox is set to style="display:hidden". Input shows 0 however the current value of getSelectionID() is 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhdTX.png)

```
<input onclick="bundle.changeSelection(this)" 
                class="change-container-classname checkbox bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>
                <?php if ($_option->getRequired()) echo 'validate-one-required-by-name' ?>"
                id="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-<?php echo $_selection->getSelectionId() ?>" 
                type="checkbox" 
                name="bundle_option[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>][]" 
                checked="checked" 
                defaultValue="0" 
                style="display:none" 
                <?php if (!$_selection->isSaleable()) echo ' disabled="disabled"' ?> 
                value="<?php echo $_selection->getSelectionId()  ?>

                "/>

                <?php if ($_canChangeQty) : ?>
                    <span class="qty-opt">
                        <select style="width:50px;"
                                id="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-<?php echo $_selection->getSelectionId() ?>-qty-input"
                                onchange="bundle.changeOptionQty(this, event)" 
                                <?php if ($memory_type) : ?> data-memory-type="<?php echo $memory_type; ?>"<?php endif; ?>
                                name="bundle_option_qty[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>][<?php echo $_selection->getSelectionId() ?>]"
                                class="qty">
                            <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= $maxQty; $i++) : ?>
                                <?php if ($i <= $stockOnHand) : ?> <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option> <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endfor; ?>
                        </select>
                    </span>

                <?php else: ?>
                    <span class="qty-opt">
                        <label><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?>&nbsp;</label>
                        <?php echo $_defaultQty ?>
                    </span>
                <?php endif; ?>
```